# Archimedes method to estimate $\pi$?

Tags: trigonometry

Does anyone know if there are additional steps beyond what is pictured below, after the triangle at point $K$ is found to estimate $\pi$?

This seems to improve a $6$ sides polygon to a $12$ sided one, but I read that he found $\pi$ using $n$ sided polygons.

[image: a]

[Reference](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fm.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D_rJdkhlWZVQ&psig=AOvVaw1GJibKp5Gn3sW54RZBDvC_&ust=1706415542783000&source=images&cd=vfe&opi=89978449&ved=0CBYQ3YkBahcKEwiwvq232_yDAxUAAAAAHQAAAAAQEw)

Answer (score 6):

After this point Archimedes continued his approximations of the perimeter of the circle (with unit radius) by repeatedly [doubling the number of sides](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.07995.pdf):

> Archimedes first used mathematics to compute $π$ and showed that it had a value between $22/7$ and $223/71$. He did this by determining the perimeter of a polygon inscribed within a circle (which is less than the circle’s circumference), and that of another polygon outside the circle (which is greater than the circle’s circumference). He then found the average perimeter of the two. Using a hexagon, a 12-sided polygon, a 24-sided polygon, a 48-sided polygon and a 96-sided polygon, his final estimate gave a range between $3.1408$ and $3.1428$.

Converting those bounds to mixed fractions shows that:
$$3 \frac{10}{71} \lt \pi \lt 3 \frac{1}{7}$$

We know of this work by Archimedes from [Measurement of a circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_of_a_Circle), which is only a part of a longer work that has not survived.  The difficulty of getting rigorous upper and lower bounds for $\pi$ is largely one of getting respective rational bounds on irrational square roots, a difficulty compounded by the need to carry out arithmetic without the advantage of modern positional notation.  However [Wilbur R. Knorr](http://users.uoa.gr/%7Eapgiannop/Sources/Knorr-Archimedes-circle.pdf) presents compelling evidence that Archimedes did increase the accuracy of the approximation further in calculations that are not preserved.